# Form angular 2 new date

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

Hello i am trying to fill a form i want that the field date take our current date and user can only read it .
I tried to did this but it doesn't worked .

```
        <div class="form-group">
        <label class="form-control-label"  for="field_date">Date</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input id="field_date" type="text" class="form-control"     
       name="date" ngbDatepicker  
       #dateDp="ngbDatepicker" [(ngModel)]="demande.date"
         value="new Date()"  readonly />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: why use a date picker on a readonly input ?

Comment: yes i did but it shown empty look to the code that i puted

Answer (score 0):

In its TS file have this,

`

```
 demande : any;
 today = new Date();
 dd: any;
 mm: any;
 yyyy: any;
```

`

and in Constructor

`

```
  this.dd = this.today.getDate();
  this.mm = this.today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
  this.yyyy = this.today.getFullYear();

  if(this.dd<10) {
    this.dd='0'+this.dd
  } 

  if(this.mm<10) {
    this.mm='0'+this.mm
  } 

  var date = this.mm+'/'+this.dd+'/'+this.yyyy;
  this.demande = { "date": date}
```

`

Try it and let us know.

Comment: I think what you wrote in TS file is correct . i write this in html

Comment: <input id="field_date" type="text" class="form-control" name="dem" ngbDatepicker  #dateDp="ngbDatepicker" [(ngModel)]="demande.date"
                       value="demande"   />

Comment: But the inpu text is empty

Comment: I have tried it by removing `value, #dateDP and ngbDatePicker` from input field and it worked for me.

Comment: it is always empty what did you write in html exactly ?

Comment: `<form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="form-control-label"  for="field_date">Date</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input id="field_date" type="text" class="form-control"     
           name="date" [(ngModel)]="demande.date" readonly />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>`